# Cannot merge JSON in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have problem with merging JSON's.

I have a ajax query which is asking my database for records. Unfortunately I must set the return records Limit(1000 records). In my database are 3122 records. That's mean that I must create a 4 queries. I receive the records from database in JSON. After every query I`m trying to merge the old one JSON with the new one. Unfortunately for now I only overwrite my old JSON.

Example JSON answer:

> {
>
> "d":[
>
> {
>
> "data":{
>
> "name":"John","surname":"Smith","year":"21"
>
> },"city":"New
>   York","Street":"Wall
>   Street"
>
> },{
>
> "data":{
>
> "name":"George","surname":"Smith","year":"26"
>
> },"city":"Las Vegas","Street":"Ceasar"
>
> }]"

All return JSON's have the same structure but different data.

My JS code look Like that:

```
var jsonVar;

function createQuery(itemCount) {

    var top = 1000;
    var skip = 0;
    var urlQuery = databaseURL+skip;

    if (itemCount > 1000) {

        var loopQuery = Math.round(itemCount / 1000);

        for (var i = 0; i < loopQuery + 1; i++) {

            skip = 1000 * i;
            urlQuery = databaseURL+skip;

            var call = $.ajax({

                url: urlQuery,

                type: "GET",

                dataType: "json",

                async: false,

                headers: {

                    Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"

                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    merge(jqXHR);
                }

            });

        }
      alert(jsonVar.responseText);
    } else {

    }


    function merge(jqXHR) {
        alert(jqXHR.responseText);
        jsonVar = $.extend(jsonVar, jqXHR);
    }
```

In first step jsonVar is empty, but jqXHR contains 1000 records.

Second step jsonVar = 1000, jqXHR = 1000

Third step jsonVar = 1000, jqXHR  = 1000 //jsonVar must contains 2000records

Fourth step jsonVar = 1000, jqXHR  = 122 //jsonVar must contains 3000records

In

> alert(jsonVar.responseText)
>   before else jsonVar must contain 3122 records but there are only 122.

Any Idea what I'm doing wrong?

---

**EDIT**

I made some modification of my code.

I almost solved my issue but like I wrote - "almost"

My merge function is calling four times. `$.extend` and `$.merge` are overwriting the previous value, because all JSON's have the same parameters.

That's why in `merge()`I add a `$.concat` function.

It's working almost perfect. The problem is only on second step.

1. Step first- call `$.extend(jsonVar,data.d)` -> data.d length 1000 // jsonVar length 1000 from 0 to 999  Good :)
2. Step two - call `$.concat(jsonVar,data.d)`-> data.d length 1000 // jsonVar length 1001 from 0 to 1000  Bad :( `$.concat(jsonVar,data.d)` add only last record from data.d to jsonVar
3. Step two - call `$.concat(jsonVar,data.d)`-> data.d length 1000 // jsonVar length 2001 from 0 to 1999   Almost Good :| `$.concat(jsonVar,data.d)` add all records
4. Step two - call `$.concat(jsonVar,data.d)`-> data.d length 122 // jsonVar length 2123 from 0 to 2122   Almost Good :| `$.concat(jsonVar,data.d)` add all records

I don`t know why in step 2 only last record from data.d is added to jsonVar

Here is my code

```
var jsonVar;

function createQuery(itemCount) {

    var top = 1000;
    var skip = 0;
    var urlQuery = databaseURL+skip;

    if (itemCount > 1000) {

        var loopQuery = Math.round(itemCount / 1000);

        for (var i = 0; i < loopQuery + 1; i++) {

            skip = 1000 * i;
            urlQuery = databaseURL+skip;

            var call = $.ajax({

                url: urlQuery,

                type: "GET",

                dataType: "json",

                async: false,

                headers: {

                    Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"

                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    merge(data);
                }

            });

        }

    } else {

    }


    function merge(data, i) {
        alert(data.responseText);
        if(i == 0){
            jsonVar = $.extend(jsonVar,data.d);
        }else{
            jsonVar = $.concat(jsonVar,data.d);
        }

            $.concat||$.extend({concat:function(b,c){var a=[];for(x in arguments)a=a.concat(arguments[x]);return a}});
    }
```

Comment: I am not quiet sure with this but wouldn't ist be `jsonVar = $.extend(jsonVar.d, jqXHR);` As the `d` key will replaced as it is always the same key. Make sure you have jsonVar.d initialized before its first use.

Comment: Unfortunately on beginning jsonVar is empty. And on first step it return me a error 'Cannot read property 'd' of undefined'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks for @RakeshChouhan.

I fix a little my code and thanks of `$.merge` is working like I want.

On first step I'm adding a object to the `jsonVar` and after merge I remove it.

I do this because on the on the beginning `jsonVar` is empty and `$.merge` return error that it cannot return `length` of undefined(`jsonVar` is empty).

Here is my code:

```
var jsonVar;

function createQuery(itemCount) {

    var top = 1000;
    var skip = 0;
    var urlQuery = databaseURL+skip;

    if (itemCount > 1000) {

        var loopQuery = Math.round(itemCount / 1000);

        for (var i = 0; i < loopQuery + 1; i++) {

            skip = 1000 * i;
            urlQuery = databaseURL+skip;

            var call = $.ajax({

                url: urlQuery,

                type: "GET",

                dataType: "json",

                async: false,

                headers: {

                    Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"

                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    merge(data);
                }

            });

        }

    } else {

    }


    function pairJson(data,i) {

        if(jsonVar == undefined){
            jsonVar = [{name:'delete me'}];
        }

        jsonVar = $.merge(jsonVar,data.d);

        if(i == 0){
            jsonVar.splice(0,1);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the given code the line inside your merge function

```
 jsonVar = $.extend(jsonVar, jqXHR);
```

creates problem because you are extending the jqXHR (which is a superset of the XMLHTTPRequest object) properties in jsonVar.

try this code,

```
var tempdata = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
jsonVar = $.merge(jsonVar,tempdata.d);
```

Try this sample code :

```
var tempData =    {

"d":[

{

"data":{

"name":"John","surname":"Smith","year":"21"

},"city":"New York","Street":"Wall Street"

},{

"data":{

"name":"George","surname":"Smith","year":"26"

},"city":"Las Vegas","Street":"Ceasar"

}]

}
var jsonVar =    [

{

"data":{

"name":"John","surname":"Smith","year":"21"

},"city":"New York","Street":"Wall Street"

},{

"data":{

"name":"George","surname":"Smith","year":"26"

},"city":"Las Vegas","Street":"Ceasar"

}];
jsonVar = $.merge(jsonVar,tempData.d);

console.log(jsonVar);
```

Comment: Unfortunately even first step cannot be complete. I receive this error: "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined "
When I change $.merge to $.extend it is working but it is the same issue. It`s only overwriting JSON's

Comment: then it may be some problem with your json response.